# how to add time to the each measurement value in a text file using matlab

Tags: matlab

My code follows here:

```
fid1=fopen('pq.txt','w');
fprintf(s,'PR1%r%n'); %//this is the command for pressure measurement
while true %// it is a real time measurement and wants loop to execute    
           %// infinity times until i press CTRL+C
    out=fscanf(s);
    sr=datestr(clock,0); %//for displaying time
    if ~isempty(out)
        fprintf(fid,[out,sr])%//-->for displaying both value and the time taken 
    end
end
fclose(fid1);
```

I need my result to look like this:

```
out1 date and time 
out2 date and time
```

The attempt above unfortunately doesn't display it like this.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this code run and display _anything_ at all ?  Or do you just not like the format of what it outputs ?

Comment: yes this code just displays out= 0, pressurevalue where 0 means measurement data 'ok ' followed by pressure value...

Comment: you use `fid1` at the beginning and end of the code, but `fid` in the middle. Is that intentional or just a typo error ?

Comment: its just typing error

Comment: when you press `CTRL-C` you interrupt the program/script and the line `fclose(fid1);` is not executed ... so if you do not `fclose` your file manually _after_ you interrupted the program, the file is still open so you may not see the proper content inside your file.

Comment: Ya ..valid point. thankyou hoki

Comment: add the line : `onCleanup( @() fclose(fid1) ) ;` just after you open the file, this way it will be closed automatically even if you do a `CTRL-C`.

Comment: do u mean after this statement fid1=fopen('pq.txt','w'); i have to add the line..